# React Native - Webview files not loaded on device

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a react native app for production on iOS device.

In this project I am loading a local html page. Currently I am using the [`WebView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html) component.

```
<WebView source={{require('./webapp/index.html')}}/>
```

And below is `webapp/index.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Foo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am building for production by following the steps listed here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#building-your-app-for-production (v0.34)

How can I make sure that `index.html` is able to load `js/script.js`?

Comment: Daniel, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No I haven't. I I did realise you could probably upload the file to a server and reference it.

Comment: For me it is working properly on simulator. On device, Yes it is not loading the .js files.  I used command 
react-native bundle  --dev false --assets-dest ./ios --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle

  This is creating assets folder and then I added all js files which loads on webView to this folder. I inspected webView in Safari browser. All js files are loaded now.

Comment: @Sujit I want to deploy a react app inside android webview, could you please elaborate the steps of deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely we need own server.I was looking for this also and I haven't found any relevant answer to this question too.

Answer (score 0):

I have [react-native-webview-bridge](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge) [here](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge/issues/109)it seems that now is right inside react-native core but i doubt we can use `allowFileAccessFromFileURLs`... i will update this answer if i find out something else

Comment: have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use a tool like [inliner](https://github.com/remy/inliner/blob/master/docs/usage.txt) to insert all the file contents (you might need the dot in your path strings) in my html automatically and then use the html string in my app.

I import my html string in a way that works well for ios and android by implementing [this](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/746#issuecomment-519662691) with the current versions of the libraries mentioned.